# Android activity: Generating a string value with an flow-based node system

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-custom-view, blockly

I want to create an activity in which you can insert/remove/move/connect nodes between each others and based on them to generate a string value that would be later sent through Bluetooth to an other device.

Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBul2.png)

And the resulting string should look like:

```
`"do[i<0-2>]:
{case[i]:
{0:"Hello ",1:"World",2:"!"}
}"
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to start creating the view where the nodes will be placed and the nodes themselves

I think that the "workspace" should be just a simple empty view where you can pan and zoom in/out

But for the nodes I have no idea where to start because they need to be able to have multiple inputs/outputs... maybe I need to create a custom veiw/component but like i said :( i don't know how to start

Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT:
I have decided to use Google's Blockly to generate the string, I have customized the block the way I need to generate the string, but I can't figure it out how to get the "code" generated as a string so I can use it later... does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Are you using Blockly for Web (in a WebView) or Blockly for Android?

Comment: I am using Android

Answer (score 0):

Blockly for Android uses a [`CodeGenerationRequest.CodeGeneratorCallback`](https://github.com/google/blockly-android/blob/master/blocklylib-core/src/main/java/com/google/blockly/android/codegen/CodeGenerationRequest.java) to pass the code string back to the application.

See this example from the [TurtleActivity](https://github.com/google/blockly-android/blob/master/blocklydemo/src/main/java/com/google/blockly/android/demo/TurtleActivity.java):

```
private final CodeGenerationRequest.CodeGeneratorCallback mCodeGeneratorCallback =
        new CodeGenerationRequest.CodeGeneratorCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFinishCodeGeneration(final String generatedCode) {
                // Sample callback.
                Log.i(TAG, "generatedCode:\n" + generatedCode);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), generatedCode,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String encoded = "Turtle.execute("
                                + JavascriptUtil.makeJsString(generatedCode) + ")";
                        mTurtleWebview.loadUrl("javascript:" + encoded);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```